# How to check internet connection (on remote host) using paramiko or sshtunnel in python?

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, paramiko, ssh-tunnel, internet-connection

My code:

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=remote_host, username=remote_user, password=remote_password, port=remote_port)
```

As I understand, if there are no exception: successfully connected. So how to check internet connection on remote host?